# js function not working on IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, icefaces

I have a div and on mouseover I show an `ice:menuPop` with this function:

```
function fireContextMenu(element, event) {
   if (element.getAttribute('oncontextmenu')) {
      element.oncontextmenu = new Function ('event', element.getAttribute('oncontextmenu'));
      element.oncontextmenu(event);
   }
}
```

calling it like:

```
onmouseover="fireContextMenu(this, event);"
```

On Chrome is working perfect but on IE it does not appears.
I suppose it's something wrong in the js or IE8 does not support hover of div?

Comment: As an aside, have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/259614/unobtrusive-javascript-with-jquery-good-10-minute-tutorial

Comment: Icefaces *shudders*.... `new Function` *screams*

Comment: So, every time the mouse moves over your element, you want to to set the "oncontextmenu" attribute to a new function ... really?  Do you think this will work the second time the mouse moves over the element?

Comment: `getAttribute` is hideously broken unless you are using IE8 Standards Mode. This doesn't have a hope if you are in Quirks mode or IE 7 Compatibility Mode. `getAttribute` is best avoided in favour of direct property accessors.

Comment: @Pointy: yeah, it's working. If you can suggest a better way I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Hmm if it's working it's probably because the function established in the previous call is converted back to a string and then re-made into a new function.

Comment: the single problem I see now is how to get onContextMenu value in IE? so a workaround for this: element   .getAttribute('oncontextmenu') would be welcome...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

No longer use the js function but use directly the value of oncontextmenu.

For my case:

```
onmouseover="Ice.Menu.contextMenuPopup(event, 'frmMainMenu:menuPopupCBM_sub', 'frmMainMenu:divMenuPopupCBM');return false;"
```