# Pass the value of a textbox as a parameter to a Javascript function without submit button

Tags: javascript, jtextfield, jquery-events, keycode

I am writing because I have a problem with the passage of the value of a textbox without the submit button, but managing the event from the keyboard.
The goal is to launch the function when I click the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. I wrote this code, but for now it does not work:

```
 <form method="GET">
<input type="textfield"  id="testo_libero" onkeydown="javascript: if (event.Keycode==13) desc_ricerca(this.value);">
  </form>
```

In the Javascript file:

```
function desc_ricerca(valore){
     console.log("valore"+valore);
 }
```

Can anyone help me?
I tried that but nothing ...

```
   function desc_ricerca(valore){    
     var cat = $("#testo_libero").val();
     console.log(cat);
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're using jQuery. If so, you should look into using [unobtrusive JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/259614/unobtrusive-javascript-with-jquery-good-10-minute-tutorial). (You can write unobtrusive JavaScript even without jQuery, but jQuery makes it *so* much easier).

For example, your code can be rewritten as follows:

**HTML:**

```
<form method="GET">
    <input type="textfield"  id="testo_libero">
</form>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('#testo_libero').on('keydown', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode != 13) return;
    console.log('valore ' + this.value);
    return false;
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wS5Db/